# How to access Python dependencies when SSH'ing to Paketo image?

Tags: python, buildpack, paketo

I have an image built using the [Paketo Python Buildpack](https://paketo.io/docs/howto/python/). It executes the command in the `Procfile` fine including python dependencies. However, when I exec on to the running instance e.g. using [ecs exec](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-exec.html) in order to run an ad-hoc script I've found it doesn't have access to the installed python dependencies e.g.

```
$ python3 -m scripts.my_script
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/workspace/scripts/my_script", line 4, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "/workspace/app.py", line 1, in <module>
    import connexion
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'connexion'
```

Is it possible to run python in a way which includes the dependencies in the path?
This was possible using the `/tmp/lifecycle/shell` [command](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/ssh-apps.html#ssh-env) on Cloudfoundry but is a similar thing possible when using a Paketo image?

Comment: If you want things to be automatically set up, you need to invoke the `launcher`. The `launcher` will set up the environment for you. You can see an example running with `docker` here https://buildpacks.io/docs/app-developer-guide/run-an-app/#user-provided-shell-process. I don't know how you'd do that with ECS, but if there's a way to set the entrypoint, set it to `launcher` and that should do the trick. Otherwise, after you enter the container, you could try executing `launcher $SHELL` to make a new shell that's set up with your env settings.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround. We can set `PYTHONPATH` manually to find the dependencies.
I found the `PYTHONPATH` using this command:

```
cat /layers/paketo-buildpacks_pip-install/packages/env/PYTHONPATH.prepend
```

Then I can set this when executing the script e.g.

```
PYTHONPATH=/layers/paketo-buildpacks_pip-install/packages/lib/python3.10/site-packages python3 -m scripts.my_script
```